# Download mainframe files to Unix with SFTP in binary mode

Tags: unix, sftp, mainframe

I want to download a file from Mainframe server to Linux machine using SFTP command and want to preserve EOL. It seems that the actual file does not have EOL character, where as SFTP process adds EOL character while downloading it to Linux server.

**Is there any option to download the file in Binary mode using SFTP command?**

I tried to download data from Mainframe server using FTP and SFTP. FTP with Binary mode is preserving actual content of original file without any modification, whereas FTP with ASCII mode and SFTP commands are modifying the content of the file by adding EOL or any other special characters.

Comment: May be you can ask this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What "SFTP command"? OpenSSH? OpenSSH `sftp` never modifies the file anyhow. If your file is modified, it must be the server that does it.

Comment: But anyway, please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think SuperUser is a better forum for this.  Unix.stackexchange.com will likely not have any z/OS representation for USS

Comment: As advised, moved my question to Super User with more context.

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked by enabling binary mode of transfer in SFTP session:

```
ls /+mode=binary
```

The default was set to ASCII.

```
sftp> ls /+ /+/clientcp=ISO8859-1 /+/error.log /+/loglevel=I /+/mode=text /+/servercp=IBM-1047 /+/trim 
sftp> bye
```

I am now able to match the size of file with FTP binary and SFTP binary.

Comment: Does this mean setting to binary is not supported by server?
{
Or could this be client problems

Connecting to 164.10.50.21...
SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP
Password:
sftp> ls /
/Inbox
sftp> ls /+mode=binary
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
Can't ls: "/+mode=binary" not found
sftp>
}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had issues with binary files and sftp. If you want to download a text file, you should use scp, unless it's in ASCII, in which case I would think sftp should work fine.

Are you trying to download a file from the hierarchical file system or from a dataset? I don't think datasets are supported with sftp (you would use FTP for that or Secure FTP).

Comment: *"If you want to download a text file, you should use scp, unless it's in ASCII, in which case I would think sftp should work fine."* - I do not think you are correct here. In general the common `sftp` and `scp` implementation (OpenSSH) support binary transfers only, both.

Comment: Dovetailed Technologies SFTP server supports "classic" z/OS datasets.

Answer (score 0):

On z/OS there are basically three ways to move content based on your question.  First is `FTP`, second is `scp` and the third is `sftp`.

Also, its important to identify which fileset you are trying to access; MVS or USS.  MVS files are different than traditional **nix* file systems.  MVS files are generally fixed or variable in nature.  As such, they do not rely on line terminators like \n or \r to terminate the line.  The record length is available at the time of reading.  USS files would have line terminators.

FTP is services are provided by a daemon that is part of the Communication Server product.  It provides most modes of transfer as well as extensions to deal with platform specific items as they relate to the MVS name space.  You can also access Unix files as well.  Conversions like ASCII (IBM-1047 -> UTF-8) are supported or binary (just move the data and don't touch it).

`scp` is delivered as part of the OpenSSH implementation on z/OS and it always transfers in a character mode and will assume an encoding change to / from EBCDIC to ASCII.  Its an unfortunate implementation but it is what it is.  This is due to the fact that the native code page on z/OS in EBCDIC in some form.  Don't expect transfers with scp to move data without conversion.  Only files in the USS file system are accessible.  No MVS datasets.

`sftp` uses the secure services of OpenSSH but acts like `ftp`.  Depending on your client you can set the mode to transfer ascii (conversion) or binary.  My client on Mac OS X will not allow ascii.  Probably a client limitation.  `sftp` also only allows you to move files that reside or are destined for the USS file domain.

To answer your question about binary in `sftp` the answer is yes, I use it frequently to move files to and from z/OS using binary to avoid automatic conversion.  Make sure you are transferring using *`binary`* transfer and not *`ascii`* when using `sftp`.

Comment: I do not know anything about z/OS nor about port of OpenSSH to z/OS. But in general, both OpenSSH SFTP client and server *do not support ascii mode*. At all. SFTP ascii mode is supported by SFTP version 4 and newer. OpenSSH supports version 3 only (so it's not like that the z/OS port of OpenSSH could easily add support for ascii mode, because they would have to implement SFTP version 4 for that and that is not a trivial task – that's why OpenSSH still does not support it, despite the version 4 was specified 17 years ago).

Comment: So I really doubt that *"Depending on your client you can set the mode to transfer ascii (conversion) or binary"*, as the server most likely do not support it.

Comment: @martin-prikryl  I’ll admit this one confuses me a bit.  I’ve only used binary but seen reference to ascii.  Although I have yet to find a client that supports it.

Comment: I got it worked by enabling binary mode of transfer in SFTP session(ls /+mode=binary). The default was set to ASCII.                                            
sftp> ls /+
/+/clientcp=ISO8859-1  /+/error.log           /+/loglevel=I          /+/mode=text           /+/servercp=IBM-1047   /+/trim
sftp> bye

I am now able to match the size of file with FTP Binary and SFTP Binary. @Martin Prikryl

Comment: @DilipPanda Please post it as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean setting to binary is not supported by server?
Or could this be client problem?

```
Connecting to XXX.XX.XX.XX...
SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP
Password:
sftp> ls /
/Inbox
sftp> ls /+mode=binary
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
Can't ls: "/+mode=binary" not found
sftp>
```

Or should it be ls / +mode=binary ?
(space between / and + )